# How to drop C# results from google when searching for C

Tags: c#, c, google-search

Whenever I am seaching on Google for a C specific solution, C# results come up and it gets really annoying. Is there a way to prevent the C# results from appearing in Google Search when I type C and not C#?

Comment: Hi. Is this just asking for advice in using google, or are you programmatically using google.  If its the former - its unfortunately off topic.

Comment: @iandotkelly but still its worth it, i believe most of c programmers have experianced it, so its "applicable to a large audience"

Comment: its advice on using a piece of software - i.e. google, its not a programming question.  Its probably more on topic in Superuser or Programming, but not really here.  I don't make the rules - I'm just giving advise that this is (almost) certainly going to be closed as off topic, and to explain why to the person asking.

Comment: @iandotkelly got it calm down no one has died, yet;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add -c# to your search.  eg:

```
c string concatenation -c#
```